# Filtering File objects in java to populate a jComboBox

Tags: java, swing, filenames, jcombobox

Using the code below populates my JComboBox with the complete path.   is there an easy way to filter it to only show the file name itself in the JComboBox.

```
    String path = "\\\\intdatserver1\\NY_files";
    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    final JComboBox jList1 = new JComboBox(listOfFiles);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could figure it out by yourself but if you insist...

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        fileNames.add(file.getName());
    } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
        // handle directory
    }
}
```

Comment: @Gluons It's ok, it didn't bother us. But I think that if you tried it to google it, you would find the solution faster :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `String` array or `List<String>` wiht the file names only, using the [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) method from the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class.